# Copy data from images to empty volume in kubernetes

Tags: docker

In Docker, when mounting a empty volume to a containers path, it would copy the original content from image to mounted volume.
(If you mount an empty volume into a directory in the container in which files or directories exist, these files or directories will be propagated (copied) into the volume. Similarly, if you start a container and specify a volume which does not already exist, an empty volume is created for you. This is a good way to pre-populate data that another container needs.)
[Docker Volume overview from official page](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/admin/volumes/#good-use-cases-for-bind-mounts)

However, I try to do the similar thing in Kubernetes, the mounted volume would overwrite the mount path. Here is path of my deployment yaml file.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
......
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.13
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: datavol
          mountPath: /var
      volumes:
      - name: datavol
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: oscarv1
```

In my case, path /var became empty.  How can I keep the original data under /var in my container image? When mount a volume to the pod?

Answer (score 7):

Add an init container that uses the same image you want to copy the files before mounting the volume on the application. Mount the volume you will mount on the main application into a different local directory in your container and perform a 'cp -r' into the mounted directory.  Now when the same image mounts this volume it will be pre-populated with the original contents and new content as well.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  ...
spec:
  ...
  template:
    ...
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: init-ngix
        image: nginx:1.13
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "cp -R /var/* /tmp/"]
        volumeMounts:
        - name: datavol
          mountPath: /tmp
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.13
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: datavol
          mountPath: /var
      volumes:
      - name: datavol
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: oscarv1
```

Comment: You can even use an emptyDir if that's the only use you have for the volume.